# Packaging project description vs store description and what's the entry point?

Tags: .net, wpf, visual-studio, uwp

I'm packaging a WPF application with the Windows Packaging project and on the Application tab I have 2 things that are confusing me.

**1. Display name and description - does the packaging display name and description get transferred into the actual Microsoft Store app name and description, or is it just there to describe the packaging project itself?**

**2. Description - I have an app description ready, but when you submit an app to the Dev Center you are also required to put an app description; so what's the difference between the packaging project app description? Slightly confused.**

**3. Entry point - what is the entry point and how do I declare one? I've been trying to find some resources regarding this but I couldn't find a solution**

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gD6OU.png)

Again, if I have not been clear enough, tell me please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes, the `DisplayName` in the package manifest is the name of your application that will be reserved in the Store.
2. This description will be displayed in the App Installer UI when the app is installed.
3. The `EntryPoint` is always `Windows.FullTrustApplication` for packaged WPF applications.

Please refer to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/desktop/desktop-to-uwp-manual-conversion?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5001077) for more information about how to create a minimal package manifest for packaged desktop apps manually.